# Update ViewModel Property From Task, but really slow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm implementing reading a file, and updating Item source of `ListView` in **WPF**.
But I have a problem with UI thread. Let me see you a gif that shows problems.

[image]

as you can see, I have problem Animating progress. (supported By `MaterialDesignTheme`)
It is better than not showing any update items of list view and not showing progress animation, but the quality of animation is low. 
Following source code is a part of view model.

```cs
private ObservableCollection<List<int>> originGames;
public ObservableCollection<List<int>> OriginGames
{
    get { return originGames; }
    set { SetProperty(ref originGames, value); }
}
private bool JobOnWork;
public bool BJobOnWork
{
    get { return JobOnWork; }
    set { SetProperty(ref JobOnWork, value); }
}
private async void OnFileOpenOriginGame()
{

    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    dlg.Filter = "텍스트 파일 (*.txt)|*txt";

    // when Open Dlg
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        BJobOnWork = true;
        OriginGames = new ObservableCollection<List<int>>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string oneline = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                string[] values = oneline.Split(' ');

                List<int> temp = new List<int>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    int valueint = -1;
                    bool safe = int.TryParse(values[i], out valueint);
                    temp.Add(valueint);
                }

                OriginGames.Add(temp);
            }
        }
        BJobOnWork = false;
    }
}
```

you may wondering what is `BJobOnWork` Property. It is just Binding Property For Animation. 
following xaml source code shows how `BJobOnWork` Property works.

```xml
<Button
    Width="100"
    Margin="0,30,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndeterminate="True"
    materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="{Binding BJobOnWork}"
    materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="-1"
    Command="{Binding CFileOpenOriginGame}"
    Foreground="White"
    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedLightButton}"
    ToolTip="원본 입력">
    _원본 입력
</Button>
```

To achieve smooth animation- I thought that I can move operation (reading data and update property) so I made it with C# `Task`.
so, I implemented it and following gif is result.

[image]

as you can see, there is no problem with animation. I though I did really good job. but after minutes I became embarrassed. Because after 1-2 minutes, job is not ended. It almost takes 3~5 minutes. I don't know how to figure out this situation. It seems trade-off thing to me.

following is my c# source code.

```cs
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string oneLine = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
            string[] values = oneLine.Split(' ');

            List<int> temp = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                int valueInt = -1;
                bool safe = int.TryParse(values[i], out valueInt);
                temp.Add(valueInt);
            }

            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                OriginGames.Add(temp);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        }
    }
});
```

I hope there is better solution for this, but If I don't have any choice then I'll choose first one solution. Is there any approach to achieve good UI thread and good background work with fast as first one solution?
thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried to use `DispatcherPriority.Background` in your `Task`? Also referring to material design guides (to check the animation performance)

Comment: Do not invoke Dispatcher in while loop. Populate a local list inside the while loop and Dispatcher invoke only once after the while loop is over.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I found that this is caused by updating items source of list view every single row. I just removed `BeginIvnoke` Line and I made temporary object that hold same data collection `OriginGames`. and after await Task.Run ends, I put temporary object to collection `OriginGames`. It works fast as first solution. I'm thinking about not update rendering on data binding Items.

Comment: @JeongYoHan You can try to check this [article](https://thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/) or try to use `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` Updating the collection using batches instead of single item can also help

Comment: @Insane, yes. after wrote this post. I tried it and works good. but `OriginGames` property have some dependency on view -I'm fine with not displaying listview item my code works on while loop, but I want to display `OriginGames.Count` bottom of View in while loop. I'm figuring out how to solve this problem.

Comment: @JeongYoHan, Updating the count can also disturb the animation in progress. You should update the count every say 1 or 2 seconds (On DispatcherPriority.Background)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, your suggestion is impressive. with AsyncObservableCollection which described in that post, I don't need `BeginInvoke`. I can update `OriginGame`(that is viewmodel property) in another thread. but It's speed is slow as second scenario in post. But very thank you for your answer. I learn from your suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after got answered from Insane, I implement with this ways.

1. Do not update property that is bound in every loop.
2. If you want update some property that is bound, make timer and achieve it through it.

following gif shows my achievement.
[image]

following source code is c# source code. first, I create local Collection `bb`. (do not blame me for variable naming XD ). And to update count of list in view, I need to add new property `OriginGamesCnt`, `ExceptGamesCnt`. I tried updating `OriginGames` `ObservableCollection` in `DispatcherTimer`, but It also generate delay and need `lock` keyword to thread safe with `bb` Collection.

so following source is my final solution source code.

```cs
private async void OnFileOpenOriginGame(string param)
{

    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    dlg.Filter = "텍스트 파일 (*.txt)|*txt";

    ObservableCollection<List<int>> bb = new ObservableCollection<List<int>>();
    // when Open Dlg
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        if (param.Equals("Origin"))
        {
            BJobOnWorkOriginBtn = true;
            OriginGames = new ObservableCollection<List<int>>();
        }
        else if ( param.Equals("Erase"))
        {
            BJobOnWorkExceptBtn = true;
            ExceptGames = new ObservableCollection<List<int>>();
        }

        DispatcherTimer dt= new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
        dt.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                if (param.Equals("Origin")) OriginGamesCnt = bb.Count;
                else ExceptGamesCnt = bb.Count;
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);

        };

        dt.Start();

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string oneLine = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                    string[] values = oneLine.Split(' ');

                    List<int> temp = new List<int>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                        int valueInt = -1;
                        bool safe = int.TryParse(values[i], out valueInt);
                        temp.Add(valueInt);
                    }

                    bb.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        });
        dt.Stop();

        if (param.Equals("Origin")) BJobOnWorkOriginBtn = false;
        else BJobOnWorkExceptBtn = false;

        if (param.Equals("Origin"))
        {
            OriginGames = bb;
            OriginGamesCnt = bb.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            ExceptGames = bb;
            ExceptGamesCnt = bb.Count;
        }
    }
}
```